# Update Outlook addin based on ClickOnce .vsto hash change

Tags: vsto, clickonce

I have a ClickOnce server set up to host Outlook plugins.  It automatically serves whichever the current version is to client machines.

When the plugin version changes, it updates perfectly.  But if one of the configuration files within the version changes, I regenerate the manifest, but it won't update because it sees the .vsto pointing to the same version number.  It ignores the change to the digital signature DigestValue:

```
<dependency>
    <dependentAssembly dependencyType="install" codebase="MyAddin.dll.manifest" size="12345">
    <assemblyIdentity name="MyAddin.dll" version="1.0.0.25" publicKeyToken="1234567890abcdef" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="msil" type="win32" />
        <hash>
            <dsig:Transforms>
                <dsig:Transform Algorithm="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:HashTransforms.Identity" />
            </dsig:Transforms>
            <dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha256" />
            <dsig:DigestValue>********************************</dsig:DigestValue>
        </hash>
    <dependentAssembly>
</dependency>
```

The only part of the sample that changes is the ********** (and obviously the .vsto signature at the bottom).

If I try to change any of the other values, it complains that the .vsto definition doesn't match the .dll.manifest definition, or the .dll.manifest definition doesn't match the target assembly.  I don't want to require a new build just because a .config file changed.

How can I force Outlook to notice the manifest change so it will actually install, instead of thinking it's exactly the same with no changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the relevant question on Stackoverflow for someone trying to do the same thing:

[How to update just one DLL in a ClickOnce installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574713/how-to-update-just-one-dll-in-a-clickonce-installation)

All it requires is changing the version number.  But it has to be changed in 3 places, or it will complain about not manifest versions not matching.  This version number DOES NOT have to match any of the .dll files that are being deployed (even though it shows up under tag "assemblyIdentity", which is confusing).  The version can be generated new each time any file changes to force an update (auto-increment, hashing, timestamp, random number, however you like).

I wasn't able to get it working before because I was only updating 2 of the references, not all 3.

First reference to this version number is found at the top of the application manifest:

```
<asmv1:assemblyIdentity name="MyAddin.dll" version="w.x.y.z" publicKeyToken="1234567890abcdef" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="msil" type="win32" />
```

Second place is at the top of the deploy manifest:

```
<asmv1:assemblyIdentity name="MyAddin.vsto" version="w.x.y.z" publicKeyToken="1234567890abcdef" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="msil" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" />
```

And the third place is inside the deploy manifest:

```
<dependentAssembly dependencyType="install" codebase="MyAddin.dll.manifest" size="12345">
    <assemblyIdentity name="MyAddin.dll" version="w.x.y.z" publicKeyToken="1234567890abcdef" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="msil" type="win32" />
```